# translate pascal to c++

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

The following code runs in the ItemClickEx event of a firemonkey ListView.  I want to know how to do this in C++.

```
procedure TfrmCategory.lstListCategoryItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject; 
                         ItemIndex: Integer; const LocalClickPos: TPointF;
    const ItemObject: TListItemObject);

begin
    if ItemObject is TListItemAccessory then
     begin
      ShowMessage('Acessory clicked');
     end;

end;
```

Source: [link here.](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=107742)

I don't know how to do the "if ItemObject is TListItemAccessory" in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ equivalent to Delphi's `is` operator is `dynamic_cast`, eg:

```
void __fastcall  TfrmCategory::lstListCategoryItemClickEx(const TObject *Sender,
    int ItemIndex, const TPointF &LocalClickPos, const TListItemObject* ItemObject)
{
    if (dynamic_cast<const TListItemAccessory*>(ItemObject))
        ShowMessage(L"Acessory clicked");
}
```

Comment: That works great, thank you.  I just code as a hobby, so I'm not a pro.  But, should i have been able to figure that out from Embarcadero's documentation?  You are a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like it is as simple as:

```
  if (ItemObject->Name == "I") {
     ShowMessage("Item Image clicked");
  }
  if (ItemObject->Name == "T") {
     ShowMessage("Item Text clicked");
  }
  if (ItemObject->Name == "A") {
     ShowMessage("Item Accessory clicked");
  }
```

This works on iOS as well as Win.